# RxJS send a request by Subject

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a problem with an existing project that I have to adapt to send an http request.

This part have two services : Service A and Service B and the Service A implements the Service B

In the Service A contain a "save" function like this:

```
class Service A {
 
  private myServiceB: ServiceB;
  constructor(serviceB: ServiceB){
    this.myServiceB= serviceB
  }

  save = () => this.myServiceB.launchSave.next();
}
```

```
class Service B {
 
  launchSave = new Subject<void>()
  saveMyElement = this.launchSave.pipe(
     tap(()=>console.log("in pipe"),
    // here some process and http request
  )
}
```

globally the calls to perform the processing are done like this in the project so I have no reason why it is not triggered.

I don't even fit into the pipe () function
since the message is not displayed but the save () function is correctly called if I put a log.

Do you have an idea to resolve the issue?

Thank you

Comment: You are just `next`ing your Subject, but that Subject needs to be subscribed.

Comment: Ok, but I haven't seen a 'subscribe' anywhere ... After some research I saw that a subscribe was needed and I tested but it doesn't work. Where to put it? I think I'm doing it wrong

Comment: If you show where you're subscribing to it, you can get better responses. But this is the general idea: `this.launchSave.subscribe((res)=> {console.log("in subscribe")})`